# Buffer.toString('binary') adds "new characters"

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, encoding, buffer

I'm trying to compress/decompress this file: [Sample of contents of sum](http://corpus.canterbury.ac.nz/descriptions/cantrbry/SPRC.html) (which can be downloaded [The Canterbury Corpus](http://corpus.canterbury.ac.nz/descriptions/#cantrbry)).

When I read it using `fs.readFile(path, callback)`, I receive a Buffer and I need to convert this buffer to a string in order to compress, and after that, need to save it again as a file.

The problem is that the `Buffer.toString('binary')` seems to be modifying the content.

If I run

```
console.log('original: ', sumBuffer)
let newBuffer = Buffer.from(sumBuffer.toString('binary'))
console.log('modified: ', newBuffer)
```

I get this:

> original: <Buffer 7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 01 0b 98 00 00 00 34 00 00 91 50 00 00 00 00 00 34 00 20 00 05 00 28 00 1a ... >
>
> modified: <Buffer 7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 01 0b c2 98 00 00 00 34 00 00 c2 91 50 00 00 00 00 00 34 00 20 00 05 00 28 ... >

In the second one, there are some `c2` character appearing where before had nothing.

`modified: <Buffer 7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 01 0b >>c2<< 98 00 00 00 34 00 00 >>c2<< 91 50 00 00 00 00 00 34 00 20 00 05 00 28 ... >`

Why is this happening? How can I get rid of this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you see the pattern of where the `c2` is inserted? If all you are trying to do is duplicate a buffer (which seems to be what you want) then there are better ways to do that - since `sumBuffer` is a Buffer, just use `Buffer.from(sumBuffer)` - as a side note, I think `let newBuffer = Buffer.from(sumBuffer.toString('binary'), 'binary')` would work too

Comment: as for why it's happening ... `Buffer.from(string, encoding)` - default encoding is `utf8` ... it has something to do with the bytes with value greater than 0x7f (i.e. 0x98, 0x91 in your example) - I'm not exactly sure what is happening, which is why I've made this a comment not an answer

Comment: @JaromandaX [Look at this image](https://imgur.com/IQOXjhL). On the left side, is node and on the right it's python. Its being inserted before the characters that are shown as "?" on python and as the unrecognized symbol on node (white background with "?" in the center).

Comment: If I use "utf-8" than the mismatch is even bigger when going back to buffer.
As why I'm doing that: I need to compress/decompress this file using mtf, bwt and huffman encoding. Thefore, I need to read the file as string, compress, then decompress and recreate the file. The code I've shown is just to summarize the main problem.

Comment: I didn't say you should use utf-8!!!! What I said was that you **ARE** using utf8 in `let newBuffer = Buffer.from(sumBuffer.toString('binary'))` - as for code you haven't shown ... you need to be aware of the buffer encoding and what certain functions use as a default encoding, and specify the decoding yourself if you don't want to use the default

Comment: Sorry! I did not realize that. I'll try that and let you know.
@JaromandaX you can check on the code [here](https://github.com/reenan/huffman_js/blob/master/index.js) if you want.

Comment: @JaromandaX THANK YOU! `let newBuffer = Buffer.from(sumBuffer.toString('binary'), 'binary')` did the trick. It`s complete now :D
Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Buffer.from` function with a string as the first argument takes a second optional `encoding` argument, which defaults to `utf8`

So, you code is equivalent to

```
let newBuffer = Buffer.from(sumBuffer.toString('binary'), 'utf8');
```

Since `sumBuffer` is clearly binary, what you'll want to do is

```
let newBuffer = Buffer.from(sumBuffer.toString('binary'), 'binary');
```

Note, this is the same as

```
let newBuffer = Buffer.from(sumBuffer);
```

However, as you've pointed out, the "real code" is a little more complex - I just felt the need to point it out in case some numpty comes along and says "but why don't you just ... " :p